# Seeking a combinatorial proof $\sum\limits _{k=0}^n (n-2k)^3\binom{n}{k}=0$

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem

Q: Seeking a combinatorial proof $(\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!}
)$

$$\sum _{k=0}^n (n-2 k)^3 \binom{n}{k}=0$$

Comment: I'm not sure if you would consider this "too algebraic" of an approach or not, but remembering that $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$, consider what happens if you were to run the sum from high index to low instead of low index to high.  Then consider what happens if you add two copies of the summation, one ranging from high to low and the other from low to high.

Comment: I don’t think there’s anything very combinatorial about this. $(n-2k)^3$ is an “odd function” relative to the middle of the summation, and $n\choose k$ is an “even function” relative to the middle of the summation, so the summand for $k=i$ is the negative of the summand for $k=n-i$. You’d get zero with $\sin(n-2k)$ instead of $(n-2k)^3$, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
2\sum _{k=0}^n (n-2 k)^3 \binom{n}{k}= \sum _{p+q=n} \left[ (n-2 p)^3 \binom{n}{p}+(n-2 q)^3 \binom{n}{q} \right] \\
=\sum _{p+q=n} \left[(n-2 p)^3 \binom{n}{p}+(2p-n)^3 \binom{n}{p} \right] \\
=0
$$

Comment: I'd say that this is an algebraic proof rather than a combinatorial proof which the OP asks for. -1

Comment: But it's so *elegant*! +1

Comment: Can someone elaborate on why this is actually true and what the $p+q = n$ in the bottom means?

Comment: $p + q =n$ is an assumption, taking any p and q whose sum is n. Thus one sum becomes $\Sigma_{p=0}^n$ and the other one becomes $\Sigma_{q=n}^0$

Comment: But I mean how is $2\sum _{k=0}^n (n-2 k)^3 \binom{n}{k}= \sum _{p+q=n} \left[ (n-2 p)^3 \binom{n}{p}+(n-2 q)^3 \binom{n}{q} \right]$?